# Is there a way to solve $ax + \sin(bx+c) = d$ analytically?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, closed-form

Is there a way to solve $ax + \sin(bx+c) = d$ analytically for x? Here a, b, c and d are constants.

Comment: Not in general! By the way you can approach the solutions using numerical methods.

Comment: There is no closed form solution for $\cos(x) = x$ (that is, $-x + \sin(x + \pi/2) = 0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no closed form in terms of any generally-accepted mathematical functions, as far as I am aware. In particular, the *fixed point of the cosine function*, i.e. the sole real solution of

$$\cos(x) = x$$

which is equivalent to

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) = x$$

is famously non-explicit. Hence, there can be no explicit formula for general values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ for the solutions of the equation you give.